# CSS Roll Over with Sprites & Sliding Door

Tags: css, user-interface, uibutton

Trying to find an example that has css rollover using sprites & sliding door techniques combined.

I am not css literate, so a complete example or link to a complete example would be appreciated.

All I am trying to do is to have `<a href>` buttons that are not fixed width with a nice rollover effect and the possibility to add an icon (similar to web outlook).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is based on this article (http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_styling_the_button_element_with_css_sliding_doors_now_with_image_spr/), but adapted for use with the a tag.

It is similar to @xijo 's answer, with a couple of minor tweaks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" > 
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
/* REQUIRED BUTTON STYLES: */       
a { 
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
}

a span { 
    display: block; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: hand;
}

/* OPTIONAL BUTTON STYLES for applying custom look and feel: */     
a.submitBtn { 
    padding: 0 15px 0 0; 
    margin-right:5px; 
    font-size:2em; 
    text-align: center; 
    background: transparent url(btn_blue_sprite.gif) no-repeat right -140px; 
}

a.submitBtn span {
    padding: 13px 0 0 15px; 
    height:37px; 
    background: transparent url(btn_blue_sprite.gif) no-repeat left top; 
    color:#fff; 
}

a.submitBtn:hover, button.submitBtnHover { /* the redundant class is used to apply the     hover state with a script */
    background-position: right -210px; 
}

a.submitBtn:hover span, button.submitBtnHover span {
    background-position: 0 -70px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
This is a bunch <a href="#" class="submitBtn"><span>Submit</span></a> of text.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

We did something like this and you perhaps could find it useful. In the anchor we used a span and assigned the following css to them:

html:

```
<a href="example"><span>echo</span></a>
```

css:

```
a, a:visited {
  background:   url(left.png) no-repeat scroll left;
}

.tabContainer a span {
  background:   url(right.png) no-repeat scroll right;  
  margin:       0 0 0 21px;
  padding:      0 21px 0 0;
  float:        left;
}
```

and then hover them like this:

```
.a:hover {
  background-position: -45px;
}

.a:hover span {
  background-position: -45px;
}
```

The left and right must look proportionataly of course! :)
Hopes this helps you to solve your css issues! ;)

Answer (score 1):

With just CSS there is not real rollover or sliding effect. Basically both of those techiques are based on "background-position".

Maybe this will help you:

http://kailoon.com/css-sliding-door-using-only-1-image/

But with javascript you could achive so much better looking rollover effect... :) Check out my test page and click on "click to show little bit advanced hover ;)" to see it ;)

www.arvag.net/test/jquery/

If you want something like that just say and i will try to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on exactly what you want this is very variable, but say you want a button that changes colour when the mouse is over it, and has a little image that appears next to it, this is the sort of thing you'd need:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>home<img src="sprite.png" width="16px" height="16px" alt="tinypic" /></li>
....

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li img {
display: none;
}
ul li {
background: #FFFFFF;
}
ul li:focus, ul li:hover, ul li:active {
background: #000000;
}
ul li:focus li img, ul li:hover li img, ul li:active ul li img{
display: inline;
margin-right: -16px; // should stop the button expanding
}
```

But as I said, that's a very basic stripped down answer